# Should I use mysql enum for a dynamic dropdown in a form?

Tags: php, mysql

I have several dropdown fields in my form that I need to add an "add new" option for the user to add another option to the list.  In mysql these dropdowns are currently of type enum.  I use php and jQuery ajax to capture the new option on the form.  Now I need to add that captured option permanently to the dropdown list.  Should I write php to add an enum option to the field or should I move away from using type enum in the mysql?  If the former, is there a better way than the answer here: [MySQL add fields to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651839/mysql-add-fields-to-an-enum) to do this?  I'm using Codeigniter and would like to add a function to my data model to add the option.  Something like:

```
<?php

function add_option_to_dropdown($field, $option)
{


}
```

Comment: You're making life more difficult by using `ENUM`. Especially to represent dynamic fields.

Comment: I probably am as I'm a numbskull when it comes to mysql :-)  What mysql type would you suggest to keep track of a list of options?

Comment: i would only go as far as a separate 2 column table (id, value) and then each row would represent a choice

Comment: in this case, adding / removing / sorting the values is A LOT easier :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the values of this dropdown could change quite frequently, therefore I would not be using the ENUM type. Better suited to this purpose would be a table storing the options for all of the dropdowns. For example, you could make a table called dropdown_options that has:

- An id column
- A dropdown_id column
- A option_value column
- A option_text column

That way, to get the values for a dropdown you simply need to:

```
SELECT * FROM dropdown_options WHERE dropdown_id = 1;
```

Where dropdown_id is the id of the dropdown you are generating. And to add a new dropdown value it is simply:

```
INSERT INTO dropdown_options (dropdown_id, option_value, option_text)
VALUES (1, "apple", "Apple");
```

Or in CodeIgniter:

```
$data = array(
    'dropdown_id' => '1',
    'option_value' => 'apple',
    'option_text' => 'Apple');
$this->db->insert('dropdown_options', $data);
```

Much simpler than changing the values of an enum!